# TCPClient.Read Reading in chunks of as low as 4 bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I fully understand the fact that I cannot read the max allotted if the data has not arrived yet. But is it really reasonable to read at a speed of 4 bytes? I mean if I am receiving a an image of 100000 bytes that would take way too long.

Is there an obvious issue with out I am receiving or sending my image?

**** To clarify: The below rLength changes every time sometimes I would only receive 4 bytes and only 4 bytes within that while loop other times I get 3000 and only 3000 in the loop. I am pretty sure there is more data but it seems to be stuck at reading only x amount per loop****

Here is the receiving code on server side

```
int totalBuffer, totalRecieved = 0;
byte[] totalBufferByte = new byte[4];
byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
byte[] tbuffer;
int rLength, prevLength;
stream.Read(totalBufferByte, 0, totalBufferByte.Length);
totalBuffer = BitConverter.ToInt32(totalBufferByte, 0);
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
while (totalBuffer > totalRecieved)
{

    rLength = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    totalRecieved = rLength + totalRecieved;
    Console.WriteLine("totalRecieved len: " + totalRecieved + " " + totalBuffer + " " + rLength + " " + buf.Length);
    if (rLength < buf.Length)
    {
        byte[] temp = new byte[rLength];
        Array.Copy(buf, temp, rLength);
        buf = temp;
    }
    prevLength = buffer.Length;
    tbuffer = buffer;
    buffer = new byte[buffer.Length + rLength];
    Array.Copy(tbuffer, buffer, tbuffer.Length);
    buf.CopyTo(buffer, prevLength);
}
```

Here is the sending code

```
public void SendResponse(int command, Object[] args)
{
    if (ClientSocket == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command: ClientSocket");
        return;
    }
    var serverStream = this.ClientSocket.GetStream();
    if (!serverStream.CanRead || !serverStream.CanWrite)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command: serverStream Error");
        return;
    }
    byte[] toSend = null;
    switch (command)
    {
        // 0 - genneral, 1 - handshake response
        case 0:
            toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0].ToString());
            break;
        case 1:
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                toSend = ImageToByte(bitmap);
            }
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        byte[] bufferedToSend = new byte[toSend.Length + 4];
        byte[] lengthOfSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(toSend.Length);
        Array.Copy(lengthOfSend, bufferedToSend, 4);
        toSend.CopyTo(bufferedToSend, 4);
        serverStream.Write(bufferedToSend, 0, bufferedToSend.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: "4 bytes" isn't a speed. It's just a number of bytes. You're only reading the 4 four bytes in 4-bytes-at-a-time, for the length - but on the Read side you should make sure that you've actually *read* 4 bytes. It's not clear what you're actually asking here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sometimes it the above rLength as seen in server side is looping at a constant 3000 and sometimes at a constant 4... When it loops at a constant in the thousands I can receive the image without timing out the client

Comment: I don't know if that accounts for the slow-down, but your reading logic seems way too complicated. You should try to avoid allocating buffers and copying data between buffers within the loop - instead read into the global buffer at the desired location.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok that can be done meanwhile when I wait for a possible reason why the while loop is onyl reading 4 bytes in 4 byte at a time intervals.

Comment: @user3059575: I believe the problem lies within that overly-complex buffer copying you're doing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't think I can make a global buffer as what you are seeing above is a task and if I do make a global buffer I would need to lock it from modification therefore losing the multi-client handling aspect of the server.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok sir, I will try my best and come back if I am unable to solve it by re-writing the buffer copying shenanigans

Comment: @user3059575: Well you might want to look at my answer first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least part of the problem:

```
rLength = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
...
if (rLength < buf.Length)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[rLength];
    Array.Copy(buf, temp, rLength);
    buf = temp;
}
```

Basically you're limiting your next read to *at most* the size of your previous read.

It's not clear what you're really trying to do, but it sounds like you should have something like:

```
byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
int lengthRead = stream.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
// TODO: Throw or loop if you haven't read 4 bytes...
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(totalBufferByte, 0);
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
int lengthRead = 0;
while (lengthRead < length)
{
    int chunkRead = stream.Read(buffer, lengthRead,
                                length - lengthRead);
    if (chunkRead == 0)
    {
        throw new IOException(
            "Stream ended after reading {0} out of {1} bytes",
            lengthRead, length);
    }
    lengthRead += chunkRead;
}
```

In other words, you should always ask to read "however much data is left" - without ever copying the data into new separate byte arrays.